# Prevent for loop to continue beyond length of string1 or string2

Tags: java, for-loop

In the code below I keep getting the following error when comparing the likeness of strings.

> String index out of range: 1 (where 1 is the input length)

It seems to be that if the input is less than the answer's length, it will cause this error. However, whenever I tried to add in the if statement to break from the loop if I increment higher than the length of input, it still throws this error.

```
String answer = textArea.getText().toLowerCase();
for (int i = 0; i < finalWord.length(); i++)
   {
      if (i > answer.length())
         break;
      else if (finalWord.contains(answer.charAt(i) + ""))
          {
              likeness += 1;
          }
   }
```

Comment: `if (i > answer.length())` should be `if (i >= answer.length())`, remember all arrays are 0 indexed, so if you try and get an item at the point of `array.length()`, then it will be out of bounds

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Comment: Java array indexes are ZERO-bazed.  Maximum value is yourArray. length - 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add your comparison in the for comparisan if the loop should continue.
The loop should only continue if it's smaller than final word and smaller and answer. If either of those is false, the loop shouldn't continue.

This is achieved by the `&&` AND operator. Both sides of the equations need to be true for the loop to be able to continue.

This is the comparisant you want the for loop to make

```
if(i < finalWord.length() && i < answer.length() ) {
   i++
}
```

In your code it would look like this:

```
String answer = textArea.getText().toLowerCase();
for (int i = 0; i < finalWord.length() && i < answer.length() ; i++) {
   if (finalWord.contains(answer.charAt(i) + "")) {
     likeness += 1;
   }
}
```

Just for kicks, a slightly more optimised version, by storing the string lengths in local variables you save the overhead of the function calls on the length checks.

```
String answer = textArea.getText().toLowerCase();
for (int i = 0,
     fwl=finalWord.length(),
     al=answer.length(); 
     i < fwl && i < al ; 
     i++) {
   if (finalWord.contains(answer.charAt(i) + "")) {
     likeness += 1;
   }
}
```

http://ideone.com/7zHoV4

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to

```
if (i >= answer.length())
    break;
```

Because Strings in Java starts from 0. So, at least it should be `length - 1`.